# How to match a cost or price number value only if it features a preceding currency symbol like '$'?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers, match

`It will cost you $112.52 for 302 pokemon cards to complete this order`

`It will cost you $112.52 to complete this order`

Above are two strings that I want to find the dollar value using regex. Below is my current regex:

`const match = str.match(/will cost you \$(.*) for ([0-9]+) pokemon cards to complete this order|will cost you \$(.*) to complete this order/);`

I can get `$112.52` in match[1] and match[3] for both strings.

However with this way (`([0-9]+)`), I am also matching the number of pokemon cards `302` which is NOT what I want (in match[2]). Is there a way I can ignore any number of pokemon cards and match just the dollar sign value in both strings in a single regex?

Comment: The OP might have a look at another ,late given, answer which provides two solutions where each precisely matches the OP's number values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the dollar amount and don't care about anything else in the string, you don't need to mention anything else in the string in your regex.

You could just match $ followed by numbers and dots, i.e

```
str.match(/\$([\d\.]+)/)
```

A fuller test example...

```
(function() {
    let strs = [
        "It will cost you $112.52 for 302 pokemon cards to complete this order",
        "It will cost you $112.52 to complete this order"
    ];
    
    strs.forEach(
        (str) => {
            let match = str.match(/\$([\d\.]+)/);
            console.debug(match);
        }
    );
})();
```

...outputs...

```
Array [ "$112.52", "112.52" ]
Array [ "$112.52", "112.52" ]
```

Comment: I want to be able to capture the exact verbiage around it so I'm sure it is the price of the product and nothing else

Comment: At it's simplest you could just remove the capture group (brackets) around the section that's matching the number of pokemon cards, i.e, `\$(.*) for [0-9]+` rather than `\$(.*) for ([0-9]+)`. 

However, the pipe in the middle does mean that when testing one string the price will be in match[1], and the other it will be in match[2], as both capture groups are in play.

Comment: The best solution is probably to make the part of the strings that is different optional, i.e `str.match(/will cost you \$([\d\.]+)(?: for [0-9]+ pokemon cards)? to complete this order/)`. 

Here we put the "for [0-9] pokemon cards" in a capture group (round brackets), start it with `?:` which means the string matched in this capture group wont appear in the output, and then after the capture group closes we use a `?` to say that the preceding section is optional.

This will give you the dollar amount in the same index of the resulting array for both inputs.

Answer (score 0):

use lookbehind assertion in regex

> (?<=Y)X   Positive lookbehind X if after Y

`(?<=\$)\d+`

example: https://regex101.com/r/H7Iyb6/1

reference: https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind

other way is that you can use unicode property `\p` class with `\u` flag

```js
const regex = \p{Sc}\p{Nd}+.\p{Nd}+
```

[\p example](https://regex101.com/r/oCMcNb/1)

Answer (score 0):

A precisely matching regex had to check the validity of a number value as well which follows the leading `$`. One would achieve this by regex-lookarounds where a [negative lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#negative-lookahead) would assure a single valid integer or float number value whereas the [positive lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) would support the direct [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) of the number value.

Such a regex would be as follows ...

```
/(?<=\$)(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?![.\d])/g
```

... and [the description is provided by its test/playground page](https://regex101.com/r/hjIoWb/1).

Its usage would be as follows ...

```js
const sampleText = `
  It will cost you $112.52 for 302 pokemon cards to complete this order
  It will cost you $.52 for 302 pokemon cards to complete this order

  It will cost you $2.52.523.45 for 302 pokemon cards to complete this order
  It will cost you $.52.523.455 for 302 pokemon cards to complete this order
  It will cost you $ .52 to complete this order

  It will cost you $.52 to complete this order
  It will cost you $112 to complete this order`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/hjIoWb/1]
const regXNumberValue = /(?<=\$)(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?![.\d])/g;

console.log(
  sampleText
    .match(regXNumberValue)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Since [lookbehinds are not supported by e.g. even the latest safari versions](https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind) one has to work around it. A possible solutions was the usage of an e.g. [named capturing group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups).

The above first provided regex then changes to ...

```
/\$(?<value>(?:\d*\.)?\d+)(?![.\d])/g
```

... where [the pattern gets explained by its test/playground page](https://regex101.com/r/hjIoWb/2).

Its usage needs to be changed too, from `match` to [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) followed by an additional [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping task ...

```js
const sampleText = `
  It will cost you $112.52 for 302 pokemon cards to complete this order
  It will cost you $.52 for 302 pokemon cards to complete this order

  It will cost you $2.52.523.45 for 302 pokemon cards to complete this order
  It will cost you $.52.523.455 for 302 pokemon cards to complete this order
  It will cost you $ .52 to complete this order

  It will cost you $.52 to complete this order
  It will cost you $112 to complete this order`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/hjIoWb/2]
const regXNumberValue = /\$(?<value>(?:\d*\.)?\d+)(?![.\d])/g;

console.log(
  [...sampleText.matchAll(regXNumberValue)]
    .map(({ groups: { value } }) => value)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```